# Kotlin - accessing companion object members in derived types

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

Given the following code:

```
open class Foo {
    companion object {
        fun fez() {}
    }
}

class Bar : Foo() {
    companion object {
        fun baz() { fez() }
    }
}
```

- `baz()` can call `fez()`
- I can call `Foo.fez()`
- I can call `Bar.baz()`
- **But, I cannot call `Bar.fez()`**

How do I achieve the final behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A companion object is a static member of its surrounding class:

```
public class Foo {
   public static final Foo.Companion Companion;

   public static final class Companion {
      public final void fez() {
      }

     //constructors
   }
}
```

The call to `fez()` is compiled to :

```
Foo.Companion.fez();
```

FYI: The shown Java code shows a representation of the bytecode generated by Kotlin.

As a result, you cannot call `Bar.fez()` because the Companion object in `Bar` does not have that method.